Is it still possible to connect my Wii Remotes to my PC via Bluetooth?
I am trying to build a game that supports Wii Remotes like Wii Sports, that comes with the motion support. I know Macs no longer support Wiimote connection via Bluetooth due to security reasons in an update. When I try doing it on my Windows PC, I press the SYNC button on the Wii Remote like I'm suppose to, and I am told that the connection failed. Normally the PIN I need to enter is 0000, 1111, or 1234, but they still don't connect.
I have looked into this more, and I have become aware of the Dolphin eliminator. Is there a way I can connect my PC with out Dolphin? I don't want to download anything just to make my Wii Remotes pair to my device.
My game is in JavaScript, so I'll be ok with installing a JS Library.

Thanks Pikalek for the edit.
